# db.raw with more than one paremter with knex

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

This currently works in knex:

```
knex.raw('select * from users where id = ?', [1])
```

I am trying to use more than one value as parameters, repeating some of them. Something like this:

```
knex.raw('select * from users where id = 1? and name = 2? and firstName = 2?', [1, 'someName'])
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do something like this also:

```
var params = {x1:1,dude:10};
return knex.raw("select * from foo where x1 = :x1 and dude = :dude",params);
```

it's not the first example, but it's documented [here](https://knexjs.org/guide/raw.html).

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the obvious quick solution is to simply repeat your array elements.

```
knex.raw('select * from users where id = 1? and name = 2? and firstName = 3?', [1, 'someName', 1])
```

I don't know knex, but there's nothing wrong with this solution either.

EDIT

A different approach is to use simple string interpolation through a library like kiwi:

```
var interpolateObject = {
  id: 'some_id',
  name: 'some_name',
  firstName: 'some_first_name'
};

var query = Kiwi.compose(
   "select * from users where id = %{id} and name = %{name} and firstName = %{firstName}",
    interpolateObject
    );

knex.raw(query);
```

Checkout kiwi.js

Comment: it actually works, but I would like to use some of the parameters twice

Comment: it's possible that knex does not work that way. If repeating your parameters isn't working you likely need to use a different knex method. I just looked at the documentation, but didn't see them doing things like:

'select * from user where id = 1? and name = 2? and firstName = 3?'

Instead they just had:

'select * from user where id = ? and name = ? and firstName = ?'

Thus it's likely not possible.

Comment: you shouldn't just interpolate the query string, as it could lead to an sql injection attack https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection